# Fritzbox Port Forwarding does not work

Tags: port-forwarding, ipv6, fritzbox

I use [packet sender](https://packetsender.com/) to send myself a upd-packet over my fritzbox's public ipv6-address (on port 55156).

I have enabled port forwarding from that port to my pc's port 55056 (where a upd server runs):

[image]

But Wireshark (running on sending device) tells me, the Fritzbox answers with `port unreachable`:

[image]

Due to [Giant Tree's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1157274/fritzbox-port-forwarding-does-not-work#comment1666289_1157274), I added these rules to the IPV6-Tab:

[image]

Because, the behaviour didn't change, I deleted the "normal" port forwarding rules, but still no change...

Comment: All Fritzboxes can capture out and incoming traffic to all ports via http://fritz.box/capture.lua. Maybe you see something in those wireshark reports?

Comment: No, that feature was disabled by my provider. But I still have monitored the traffic. What do you think I could have missed?

Comment: IIRC IPV6 requires additional rules in the IPV6 tab.

Answer (score 0):

I addition to [what Giant Tree proposed](https://superuser.com/questions/1157274/fritzbox-port-forwarding-does-not-work#comment1666289_1157274) I had to use my computers public IPv6-address. Didn't know it had one... :D